# Could Moses Have Failed?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, tanach

Was having a conversation with another user in which I made the argument that Moses didn't fully believe he was talking to God because he doubts he can fulfill this mission from God even with God's help. Considering that God is supposedly the creator of the entire world, was Moses's hesitation legitimate? Could he have failed God's mission even with all the help God was willing to offer him?

I'm not speaking about "What if Moses says no or decides to do a terrible job as a prophet." I'm speaking about "What if Moses does everything he can to fulfill God's mission, but could he still fail?"

Comment: היד השם תקצר? somewhat of a consistent theme with him

Comment: @doubleaa יש ל[ו] שלוחים הרבה

Comment: I liked the spirit of the question, but it is based on vague and unsubstantiated assumptions. First, start with the verses you use to conclude that Moses hesitated. Second, how did you jump from hesitation to failure? Third, define failure. Fourth, update me.

Comment: Rabbi Dessler says that after a certain stage, Moshe's *bechirah* (the way we understand it) was taken away from him.

Answer (score 1):

I would answer "yes." Rambam wrote somewhere that people have free will and can decide to use it for good or for evil as they choose. Understood this way, it is possible that Moses decides not to follow G-d's mission, either because he does not believe he had a real vision or he does not think he is up to the task. On the other hand, it is possible that G-d would intervene and force him to complete the mission. Or, find someone who will.

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what conversation you are referring but as Turk Hill said people have free will.

In fact God himself confirms the possibility of a mission failing due to free will of other people.

The Posuk Shmuel 1:16:2 says

וַיֹּ֚אמֶר שְׁמוּאֵל֙ אֵ֣יךְ אֵלֵ֔ךְ וְשָׁמַ֥ע שָׁא֖וּל וַהֲרָגָ֑נִי
וַיֹּ֣אמֶר יְ
עֶגְלַ֚ת בָּקָר֙ תִּקַּ֣ח בְּיָדֶ֔ךָ וְאָ֣מַרְתָּ֔ לִזְבֹּ֥חַ לִה' בָּֽאתִי

When Hashem told Shmuel to anoint a son of Yishai to become king, Shmuel asked that  Shaul Hamelech may find out beforehand and kill him. Hashem told him to use a ruse so that Shaul would not realize what he is going to to do. Hashem didn't say "If I told you to do it will happen safely"

While of course Hashem CAN do anything and Hashem COULD have said " There is nothing to worry about because I want this done" (see Yermaiyah 1:8)it isn't so guaranteed when you are dealing with people who have bechira. Therefore Shmuel asked about the danger.

Note: Not all Meforshim understand Shmuel's question about Shaul  hearing and killing him being because he was afraid. At least one understands  that he simply  did not want to be saved by the way of a miracle. They further point out that many neveim were sent to do dangerous things and did not bring up the danger. They distinguish between the case of a Novi being told to do something *inherently* dangerous as part of the mission and the case of Shmuel where there was no inherit danger in anointing a son of Yishai as king. There was only a side danger of Shaul finding out. Being that the danger was not intrinsic to the mission Shmuel asked about it. Otherwise he would not not have.